# webpy logging to separate log files

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl, logging, web.py

I am using webpy to host a simple web service with 2 sub-services.
I would like to log information of each sub-service into different log file using python logging package.
The below shows  test_logging.py (the main function that runs webpy), and test_classC.py (the function that does back-end service).

```
# test_logging.py

import web
from test_classC import classC

urls = (
    '/nw1', 'nw1',
    '/nw2', 'nw2',
)

class nw1:
    cc = classC('subtype1')

    def POST(self):
        self.cc.logsomething()

class nw2:
    cc = classC('subtype2')

    def POST(self):
        self.cc.logsomething()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

---

```
# test_classC.py

import logging

class classC:

    def __init__(self, subtype):
        self.nw_type = subtype
        logfile = subtype + '.log'

        self._log = logging.getLogger()
        self._log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        handler = logging.FileHandler(logfile)
        self._log.addHandler(handler)


    def logsomething(self):
        self._log.info("This is network type: %s" %self.nw_type)
```

---

Apparently I didnt write the logging correctly. When I test with the following web command using curl...

```
$ curl localhost:8081/nw1 --data-binary "hello"
$ curl localhost:8081/nw2 --data-binary "hello"
```

---

I get the same logging information in subtype1.log and subtype2.log. The first curl command generates the first two lines, and the second curl command generates the third and fourth lines.

```
This is network type: subtype1
This is network type: subtype1
This is network type: subtype2
This is network type: subtype2
```

---

How can I log the information such that

I get the following in subtype1.log following the first curl command

```
This is network type: subtype1
```

and I get the following in subtype2.log following the second curl command

```
This is network type: subtype2
```

[This is optional, but I'm curious] Also, since this is a web service, how can I make sure the information is properly logged when two users access the same web service in parallel. Eg. send the following command in parallel

```
$ curl localhost:8081/nw1 --data-binary "request_a_very_heavy_load_serv"
$ curl localhost:8081/nw1 --data-binary "request_a_very_heavy_load_serv"
```

Comment: This is strange. I'm trying for one hour now.. hmm

Comment: phew!! after 2 hours found a fix for the issue.. Check my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code.

You said,

> I get the same logging information in subtype1.log and subtype2.log

The reason is you need to create two separate, completely different logging objects. You can do it with `logging.getLogger()` by passing the name you want.

In your case it should be `self._log = logging.getLogger(self.logfile)`

2. The logs get duplicated when you call them multiple times. (You have not noticed it but that issue is there in your code.)

The reason is `logging.getLogger()` is a singleton. So every time you create an instance of `Class C` it adds another handler to the instance which causes the duplication of logs.
So I have checked `if not len(self._log.handlers):` before adding the handler.

So your final test_classC.py is as follows,

```
# test_classC.py
import logging

class classC:

    def __init__(self, subtype):

        self.nw_type = subtype
        self.logfile = subtype + '.log'
        self._log = logging.getLogger(self.logfile)
        if not len(self._log.handlers):
            self._log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
            self.handler = logging.FileHandler(self.logfile)
            self._log.addHandler(self.handler)

    def logsomething(self):
        self._log.info("This is network type: %s" %self.nw_type)
```

To test the parallel requests you can use [jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)